# Error while using 'rails server' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have installed Ruby on Rails using railsinstaller-3.2.0 [Ruby version:2.2.4 ,Rails version : 5.0.0.1].
Error:

[image: Error]
Whenever I Run `rails server` command I confront an error report like [Could not find gem 'uglifier (>= 1.3.0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.].Even if Install the required gem new error is raised for another missing gem .
How can I solve this issue , How can I install all the missing gems ?

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` ?

Comment: Yes I did it but still I face problems . [please refer the screen shot]

Comment: Try this. Go to your gem file and remove any versions present beside your uglifier gem. go to your gemfile.lock search for uglifier and remove any versions beside the uglifier gem and then bundle. This resolved my issue once.

Comment: could you please tell me , How can I do it

Comment: try this.. remove your `Gemfile.lock` file .. and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Add this gem into your gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer'
```

and

```
bundle install
```

In your terminal.

Cheers